# how to configure Postgres variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I'm beginner,
after seeing YT video [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLPYc3hJ2Cw&t=3360s) i faced an authorization issue dealing with [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)
in VScode terminal, entering `docker compose up` I receive multiple exit errors,
`.env` file written as described in video.

It seems I need to authorize port `5432`, so I went to `power shell` as admin, and approved the port for certain image (as seen on other YT video) so i won't be needing to use passwords for my local machine.

Still, every time I try to `docker compose up` I face the same issue of the need to authorize.

maybe i need to configure the env variable in different way?
Seen many YT videos with no success, your help is welcome.

1)
[image: screen shot of IDE]

2)
After inserting `docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up` in **terminal**
[result of command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3reg.png)

3)
the env. screenshot
[env script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovdAB.png)

Comment: you should write an appropriate title for your question so that others can find your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use command below to get variable input for docker-compose.

docker-compose --env-file .env.sample up

Comment: tried this command you suggested, seems it still not succeeding..
Also, edited the post with the command result screenshot for review, Maybe it will give better direction what should i do.
Thanks.

Comment: the correct command is : docker-compose --env-file .env.sample up